# Editable cell for custom cellfactory

Tags: javafx-2, tablecell

I have created a custom cellfactory for Integer. I can see the tablecell is populated but the problem is I cannot get the cell to edit mode.

Here is my cellfactory implementaion

```
public class TableCellInteger extends TableCell {

public TableCellInteger() {    }

@Override
protected void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (item != null) {
        setText(item.toString());
        setGraphic(null);
        setStyle("-fx-alignment: CENTER;");
    }
}
```

}

Here is the controller section:

```
col_VAL.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Price, Integer>("val"));

Callback<TableColumn<Price, Integer>, TableCell<Price, Integer>> integerCellFactory =
            new Callback<TableColumn<Price, Integer>, TableCell<Price, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                    return new TableCellInteger();
                }
            };


col_VAL.setCellFactory(integerCellFactory);
```

Any idea how can I implement this?

Comment: Have you tried just using a TextFieldTableCell?

Comment: TextFieldTableCell works as expected if i make 'val' as StringProperty. I have a bunch of other columns (like date & currency) for which I have to use custom cellfactory, so i am trying out with Integer first. Is anything missing in my implementation ?

Comment: Your implementation lacks any editable component, such as a TextField. You can use TextFieldTableCell with non-String columns if you [provide a StringConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn(javafx.util.StringConverter)).

Comment: If you really need to roll your own cell factory, there's an example in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) (example 12-11: "Alternative Solution of Cell Editing"). I think this is overkill though, TextFieldTableCell with appropriate StringConverters should suffice.

Comment: I made changes to my DateTime field in the exact manner and I get the cell as editable. Only difference is my val is IntegerProperty and the date filed is simple DateTime. Does this not work with bean property?

Comment: Can you post the code for the cell factory for your date column? Which DateTime class are you using?